# CSS using <div>

Tags: css, html, styling

I am using `<div>` to create  a horizontal bar across the screen. Within that horizontal bar, I have 3 more `<div>` each of a different width. They *are supposed* to be all in a row horizontally next to each other. Instead, they are on top of each other. How do I fix this?

Also, if I don't have any text within the `<div>` in my HTML code, the `<div>` does not appear. Ex: `<div>anything</div>`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUnQZ/5/)

Comment: @xec I think you will know the answer

Comment: Add `display: inline-block` in .right, .mid and .left

Comment: why not `float:left` in first div @PiLHA

Comment: @RitabrataGautam i dont know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css float:left to div and If you also don't want any text in div you should add css height to div.

```
.horizon div{
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
}
```

like this http://jsfiddle.net/KG5B3/

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUnQZ/10/)

You can float those inner DIVs. You can also use `inline-block` (not shown).

```
<div class="horizon">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="mid">middle</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <br style="clear: both" />
</div>

body {
    margin: 0;
}
.horizon {
    background: #000000;
    width: 100%;
}

div.horizon div {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 25%;
    background: #ff0000;
}
.mid {
    width: 50%;
    background: #00ff00;
}
.left {
width: 25%;
    background: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pUnQZ/5/ The red one never shows up, also, what do you mean by clear?

Comment: Sorry, sloppy can & paste. I added the clear for you so you can see what I mean.

Comment: why is the clear needed? what does it do? Is there a way I can have the div without text in it? Just have it empty but still show up what ever color?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a float, which **IS** cross-browser compliant. Also you should clear your floats which can be seen on the updated [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUnQZ/9/)

```
.horizon div{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp shows all the major browsers support the float. Also I'll add the clear in